# Inner Measure not a Measure on Power Set, and Equals Outer Measure for Lebesgue Measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is there any advice on this problem:

For $A \subset \mathbf{R},$ the quantity
$\sup \{|E|: E$ is a closed bounded subset of $\mathbf{R}$ and $E \subset A\}$
is called the inner measure of $A .$

(a) Show that if $A$ is a Lebesgue measurable subset of $\mathbf{R}$, then the inner measure of $A$ equals the outer measure of $A .$

(b) Show that inner measure is not a measure on the $\sigma$ -algebra of all subsets of $\mathbf{R}$

For (b) would the fact that $\sup(\varnothing)=-\infty$ be of use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this holds is because there is no "perfect" measure. In Axler's text, this cannot be a measure since it is not a measure on all sets of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: The reason why this holds is because inner measure is not countably additive on the sigma-algebra of all subsets of $\mathbf{R}$.